# Issues with Streaming API Responses to Frontend on AWS using Vercel's AI SDK

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, openai-api

I am currently working on a project where I use Vercel's AI SDK to stream API responses to the frontend of my application. Everything works perfectly when I run the application locally, however, **I encounter problems when deploying it on AWS(Amplify)**. I get the response but it is not streamed.

Below is the code I have for my API route and UI:

**API route**

```js
import { StreamingTextResponse, LangChainStream, Message } from 'ai';
import { ChatOpenAI } from 'langchain/chat_models/openai';
import { AIMessage, HumanMessage } from 'langchain/schema';

export const runtime = 'edge';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { messages } = await req.json();

  const { stream, handlers } = LangChainStream();

  const llm = new ChatOpenAI({
    streaming: true,
  });

  llm
    .call(
      (messages as Message[]).map(m =>
        m.role == 'user'
          ? new HumanMessage(m.content)
          : new AIMessage(m.content),
      ),
      {},
      [handlers],
    )
    .catch(console.error);

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

**Frontend Code**

```js
'use client';

import { useChat } from 'ai/react';

export default function Chat() {
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat();

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-md py-24 flex flex-col stretch">
      {messages.length > 0
        ? messages.map(m => (
            <div key={m.id} className="whitespace-pre-wrap">
              {m.role === 'user' ? 'User: ' : 'AI: '}
              {m.content}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="fixed w-full max-w-md bottom-0 border border-gray-300 rounded mb-8 shadow-xl p-2"
          value={input}
          placeholder="Say something..."
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```